# Data passed to custom filter undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, so I'm sorry if I'm asking something stupid (which I'm likely doing).

I have created a custom filter:

```
angular.module("customFilters", [])
    .filter("mainGroups", function() {
        return function(data) {
            var results = [];
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].mainGroup == 1 || data[i].mainGroup == 2 || data[i].mainGroup == 3) {
                    results.push(data[i]);
                }
            }

            return results;
        }
    });
```

I'm applying this filter:

```
ng-options="group.description for group in data.mainGroups.itemMainGroups | mainGroups | orderBy: 'description'"
```

In the console (via console.log) I can clearly see data is an array of 15 objects. `Angular.isArray(data)` also returns true. Still, I'm getting these errrors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue myself by just executing the code when `angular.isArray(data)` is true. I don't know why this works, but at least it does..

```
    angular.module("customFilters", [])
        .filter("mainGroups", function() {
            return function(data) {
                if (angular.isArray(data)) {
                  var results = [];
                  console.log(data);
                  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                      if (data[i].mainGroup == 1 || data[i].mainGroup == 2 || data[i].mainGroup == 3) {
                        results.push(data[i]);
                      }
                  }

                  return results;
                } else {
                  return data;
                }
        });
```

Comment: do you load the option list from a rest service? maybe the data may not be finished loading...

Answer (score 0):

Your filter seems to work. its maybe a data issue.

```js
angular.module("customFilters", [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
      id: 1,
      mainGroup: 1, 
      description : 'M'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      mainGroup: 2, 
      description : 'N'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      mainGroup: 3, 
      description : 'A'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      mainGroup: 4, 
      description : 'H'
    }, {
      id: 5,
      mainGroup: -1, 
      description : 'S'
    }, {
      id: 6,
      mainGroup: 1, 
      description : 'B'
    }, {
      id: 7,
      mainGroup: 2, 
      description : 'R'
    }, {
      id: 8,
      mainGroup: 3, 
      description : 'G'
    }, ];
  })
  .filter("mainGroups", function() {
    return function(data) {
      var results = [];
      console.log(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].mainGroup == 1 || data[i].mainGroup == 2 || data[i].mainGroup == 3) {
          results.push(data[i]);
        }
      }

      return results;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="customFilters" ng-controller="myController">
  <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="group.description for group in data | mainGroups | orderBy:'description'" ></select> <span>Show 6 out of 8 entries</span>
  <div ng-repeat="item in data | mainGroups"><pre ng-bind="item | json"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```